# Error on line 50: attempt to give DATA in type-declaration

Tags: fortran

I am try to compile FORTRAN 77 code and I have problems like this.

```
  integer row(nnzmax+nszero),column(nnzmax+nszero),
 +        ireg(nximax),florsm(nzimax)/nzimax*2/
  real lambda,imodel(nximax,nzimax),dm(nmmax),
 +     dum1(nmmax),dum2(nmmax),data(ndmax+nsconst),
 +     anz(nnzmax+nszero),ibmodel(nximax,nzimax),
 +     smwz(nzimax)/nzimax*-1./,spwz(nzimax)/nzimax*-1./

Error on line 50: attempt to give DATA in type-declaration
Error on line 52: attempt to give DATA in type-declaration
```

I used to work with this code,but it has been compiled with Intel Fotran Compiler. I have moved to other country so I do not have ifort installed here. I am using fort77 now. Should I try with some compilation options or?I have used this script to compile app .f from this folder.

```
#! /bin/csh -f

set list=`ls *.f`
set FLAG="-o"
echo $list
foreach file (${list})
  echo $file
  f77 ${file} ${FLAG} ${file:r}
  mv ${file:r} ../bin/.

end
```

I have changed declarations like this:

integer row(nnzmax+nszero),column(nnzmax+nszero),
 +        ireg(nximax),florsm(nzimax),
 +         data florsm /nzimax*2/
  real lambda,imodel(nximax,nzimax),dm(nmmax),
 +     dum1(nmmax),dum2(nmmax),data(ndmax+nsconst),
 +     anz(nnzmax+nszero),ibmodel(nximax,nzimax),
 +     data smwz /nzimax*-1./,
 +     data spwz /nzimax*-1./

But still I got

```
Error on line 50: attempt to give DATA in type-declaration
Error on line 53: attempt to give DATA in type-declaration
Error on line 385: Declaration error for smwz: used as variable
Error on line 385: Declaration error for smwz: may not appear in namelist
Error on line 385: Declaration error for spwz: used as variable
Error on line 385: Declaration error for spwz: may not appear in namelist
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not starting the line before column 7?

Comment: I tried with pgf90, ifort and gfortran all of them compiled that piece of code. Even though gfortran with the option -Wpedantic declared it a GNU extension.

Comment: @VladimirF Yes I have checked this.

Comment: @EdmondoGiovannozzi So I should change f77 with gfortran?

Comment: No, look at the answer, and try to correct the source in order to follow the standard first of all. If it is unfeasible, you can try a compiler that supports that extension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This fragment, and the later similar ones

```
florsm(nzimax)/nzimax*2/
```

looks like a non-standard way of initialising a variable with a sort-of `data` statement merged into the declaration.  A more standard approach would separate the two, something like

```
florsm(nzimax)
...
data florsm /nzimax*2/
```

One of the beauties of working with the Intel Fortran compiler is its long history; along the way it has picked up, and continues to accept, all sorts of non-standard features.  I'm guessing that this is one of those and is not acceptable to the other compiler you mention.

Of course, this seems to be what the error statement seems to be telling us.

A standard replacement might be

```
florsm(nzimax) = 2
```

but that takes advantage of a Fortran 90 feature which something called `fort77` might not understand either.

Comment: ANd the other two like this:     +     smwz(nzimax) data /nzimax*-1./,
     +     spwz(nzimax) data /nzimax*-1./